# Android SQLite database made accessible to multiple applications

Tags: android, sqlite

I am looking to developing and Android App store for academic purposes. I was wondering if it was possible for the SQLite database of my main application to be made accessible to the applications (dummy applications) originating from my App store. Is it also possible to have concurrent access to an SQLite database on Android.

Alternatively is it possible for the data to be stored as a file on the device and be accessible to multiple applications.

Comment: Thanks, may I use content providers when the database is encrypted?

Comment: this link is useful http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

you may create database in your sd card from where other application can also access that database.

Comment: if database is created in the domain of application then it will only be accessible by that application. so my guess is, if he create database in sd card , he can access it simply by his name because he is setting up the application , he knows the path as well.so that database will be accessible by his other applications.